# Is the word "palaver" in common use anywhere in the English-speaking world?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, history

In a sci-fi movie from 1957, an astronaut says he's "going to ***palaver***" with the cave-dwelling natives. I'd never heard the word before, but my husband—a history buff—knew it by its original meaning: a conference between a 'civilized' person (or persons) and folks from a more primitive culture. Supposedly, it has disintegrated colloquially to mean something like "meaningless blather" (probably because of the way it sounds) but when I checked that Ngram thingy, it looked as though its main use in writing is in its original sense—ironically, or not.

Is "palaver" still in use? (If so, in what part of the world is it used?) In what sense is it used?

Comment: I've heard the term numerous times (though perhaps not much in the past ten years).  Generally in a phrase similar to "that's a lot of palaver", meaning a lot of gibberish and jaw flapping with no apparent purpose.

Comment: I know it as a synonym to _parley_, and in that sense I somehow get the image of pirates... But that's probably just me

Comment: A funny thing is that in certain areas (and ages) in german this word is used a lot; even these days I hear and use it from time to time. But afaik it was adapted by germans during english speaking occupation.

Comment: ♫ ♩ *"What a palaver, what an absolute treat to see a cat and its father pick a bone in the street!"* ♪ ♬ [Les Misérables, "Plumet Attack"](http://www.metrolyrics.com/the-attack-on-rue-plumet-lyrics-les-miserables.html) or watch [video at 1:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrm4H2zLX64&t=1m15s)

Comment: It's kind of funny to see this question today, since I've been listening to audiobooks of Stephen King's Dark Tower series. This word comes up quite a bit in those books and definitely seems to be intended to sound archaic.

Comment: Just a note: The word Palaver is also used in German, similarly on the edge of common use, but in use nonetheless.

Comment: I have always taken this word to have originated from the Spanish word "palabra" in some kind of verbalized form.  If that's true, then I would expect the origin to be in the US Southwest, along with words like "Hoosegow".  But I haven't done the research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically lifted from the [German Wikipedia entry](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaver) -- the term is not that uncommon in German, though with negative connotations.

---

The word has its origins in Greek (*παραβολή*), and from there was adapted by Latin (*parabola*), Portuguese (*palavra*), and eventually, English.

The general meaning is "idle talk".

In many African cultures, this is considered good manners -- you get to know the other person before you start talking about the subject that really got you together.

The meaning your husband associated with the term is probably the way the Portuguese used it when trading with African people. I doubt the African people considering it good manners *to this day* would agree with his interpretation that it's a talk between a civilized and a savage, though.

- [The African palaver tradition and the western postmodern consensus: convergences and divergences](http://www.dialoguedynamics.com/content/learning-forum/modules/consensus-palabre/article/the-african-palaver-tradition-and?lang=en)
- [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/?term=palaver)

Answer (score 36):

Yes, I use it and so do many people that I know.

Nowadays it usually comes in the idiom *A bit of a palaver*, which refers to an argument.  Usually an argument involving more than two people.

I suspect that nowadays its use amongst younger people is dying out but it is used by my fellow Britons in our decrepitude.

Comment: Funny, we Americans associate it with the old West and cowboys jawing around the campfire. Stephen King made extensive use of it in his gunslinger series.

Comment: In my experience (UK) it's used not *strictly* for arguments, but general disorderly, heated situations of fuss, confusion, bother, people getting irritable, etc. Usually lots of talk and no action, and confused non-agreement rather than direct disagreement. For example "There was some palaver at check in because we'd been given the wrong type of tickets, but we got it sorted out in the end". I don't think I've ever seen it written down before, only spoken, it's a bit colloquial. Didn't know about the colonial history... ugghhhhh... damn history!

Comment: True, 'argument' may have been too strong a word.

Comment: I only know it from a musical: *What a palaver, what an absolute treat, to watch a cat and its father pick a bone in the street.*

Comment: `its use amongst younger people is dying out` - I consider myself quite young at 24, and I use the word. Though I would only use it to mean argument / disorderly situation. I had a bit of fun trying to explain this word to a Frenchman recently using similar words like raucous, hullabaloo and kerfuffle.

Comment: @James I'm glad to hear it.  I obviously meet a different group of 20somethings.

Comment: @Dan Bron Came here specifically to comment about Stephen King's usage in The Dark Tower as well!

Comment: @DanBron I thought the old West association was with "paladin" due to the Ballad of Paladin, Have Gun Will Travel.  Is palaver a cognate of paladin?  I remember the Gunslinger, Roland, in The Dark Tower, but I thought that was based on paladin too.

Comment: I would not use *palaver* to mean an argument, but rather a fuss or a bother, similar to the example given in @user568458's comment.

Answer (score 27):

This is a very commonly used word in the West of Scotland (Glasgow etc.). We use to mean a *disturbance* - usually about something inconsequential. So you might say, "*there was a big palaver on the bus when the inspector came on and some guy couldn't find his ticket*".

It is marginally colloquial (I don't think a police officer would use it in court, "*we were summoned to a palaver in Sauchihall St.*" - no...). Scottish colloquial synonyms would be *stushie* or *stramash*. In England, maybe *to-do* or *carry-on*.

Comment: This is the Northern Irish usage too, in my experience.

Comment: I, too, associate "palaver" with some sort of a *fuss*, *to-do* or *carry-on*. I was surprised to find on this thread that its intended use is actually to do with conversation!

Comment: Despite being from southern England I was more familiar with this use until I was recently reading some of Edgar Wallace's *Sanders* stories.

Comment: Sounds like it's used similar to the Aussie's "kerfuffle", which is a word my American ears love to hear.

Comment: It sees the same use in Australia.

Comment: "to-do" and "carry-on" are archaic in England, in a way that "palaver" isn't: we'll use it just as you do.

Comment: @fotijr: We say "kerfuffle" for the same situations in the UK, too, though that may have come from _Little Britain_, mainly.

Answer (score 8):

*Palaver* is mildly pejorative. It's often used to mean idle chat that's leading nowhere, too much talk and not enough action; sometimes it refers to talk that is intended to distract attention from the issue at hand.

I hear it used now and then, as a noun.

The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=palaver%2Cpalavering&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpalaver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpalavering%3B%2Cc0).

Here's my planetary location on the Dictionary of American Regional English map (they don't draw too good):

[image]

Comment: You need to say which planet you come from, OP's orders :)

Comment: Wow, there was a really big palaver in the 1660s! Must have been the Great Fire of London.

Comment: Must take Google's ngrams with a few grains of salt. I've found many egregious errors in the dating (and OCR'ing) of texts.

Comment: i'm from approximately that location as well.

Comment: Yeah, I never took it to mean arguing, just meaningless jaw flapping.

Comment: Connecticut is substantially larger than Montana on that map, I see, and Rhode Island is bigger than Alaska. And when did we move Hawaii to the mainland to replace Baja California?

Comment: If its at the pointer, that looks like Philly or its suburbs. I lived there for 5 years in the '90's. In my experience, that's one of those areas of the US that feels it has no accent, but I can pick out and locate easily. :-)

Comment: @Sven Yargs: the size is an analog of population density (from ~ 50 years ago, when some linguistic surveys were undertaken, if I understand correctly).

Comment: A shout out to my homeys in S.E. PA near the Twelve Mile Circle.  :)

Comment: Since this is the one 'data' oriented answer, would you happen to have done a vocab frequency search for palaver in COCA?

Comment: @Mitch:  I haven't downloaded any of the COCA datasets. What sort of frequency search did you have in mind?

Comment: @TimRomano no need to download. [Search their website](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). I see 86 hits ('the' has 25M, 'rock' has 44K, 'commode' has 206, 'adze' has 33, and 'antidisestablishmentarianism' has none.

Comment: @Mitch: I thought you meant a frequency by genre or some sort of diachronic analysis. COCA shows *palaver* is well-attested in the 21st century in a wide range of of contexts, many of them pejorative.

Comment: @TimRomano Well, such a fine frequency analysis would be wonderful, but   even with what you get from COCA, it is so much more trustworthy than Google NGrams.

Comment: I just randomly came across a NYT review from 2011 that used this word this in this sense: http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/31/theater/reviews/wittenberg-at-the-pearl-theater-review.html

Answer (score 4):

It's basically used to describe an informal chat. Depending on your intonation, you could be stressing the irrelevance of the topic of discussion (e.g. when something more important should've been addressed, or you found the topic of discussion a waste of time), or you could be stressing you just talked for hours on end with a friend.

It's not just an English word. Although I'm not sure if it's a word in proper Dutch, my regional dialect (Antwerp, Belgium) does contain it. While we use it as a verb as well, it's mostly used in my Dutch dialect as a noun.

Comment: This is a fascinating comment. But it is about Dutch right? So it's not really about English. Please move to a comment.

Comment: @Mitch The second paragraph wasn't specifically about Dutch, as I've experienced the exact same usage in English. But I can see how you construe the entire answer to be focusing on Dutch (which isn't the case). Will rephrase to make it clearer.

Comment: Etymology Online claims Portuguese.

Comment: I've *never* heard it used to mean an "informal chat" in English and didn't know about the historical meaning OP refers to. I've only heard it in the "bit of a fuss" sense, which I have heard many times.

Answer (score 4):

Here in Texas, it is occasionally used in the sense of a sit-down type discussion, possibly a negotiation.  e.g. "I went and had a little palaver with Joe about coming to work for his store." It doesn't have any negative connotations, except to denote it's not like, friends just talking with each other, there's an implication of there being some distance without making it all sound formal and highfalutin' like "conference" or "negotiation."'

Answer (score 4):

I am from Australia (I live in Melbourne but grew up in Sydney with a Scottish father, which probably matters in this context).
I use the word, usually in the phrase " a bit of a palaver ", in a mildly derogatory sense. It indicates a noisy argument or dispute, probably with a few people, but could be just 2 people.  The word would indicate that I thought dispute was  of little consequence.

Answer (score 4):

Palaver: aye thats common in the west of Scotland.  Around the same places as you would hear footer and knacker.  "What a palaver" - what a fuss.  Usually but not always referring to a needless fuss.  Eat you peas, dont make a palaver our of them.

Answer (score 4):

***Palaver*** has an entry in the Oxford English Dictionary, both as a noun and a verb.

Its etymology is given as follows:

> Etymology: Probably via early West African Pidgin < Portuguese palavra
>   word, speech, talk (13th cent.) < classical Latin parabola parable n.
>   Compare Spanish palabra (1207), French palabre grandiloquent speech
>   (1604). With the sense development compare word n. 9. Compare earlier
>   parol n., palabra n. This word appears to have been used by Portuguese
>   traders on the west coast of Africa for conversing with the local
>   inhabitants (compare quot. 1735 at sense 4), to have been picked up
>   there by English sailors (compare quot. 1771 at sense 4), and to have
>   passed from nautical slang into colloquial use. Compare fetish n.

Several of the noun senses concern idle talk etc, as has been described by responders here.

However the use with which I have been familiar all my life, and that in which I and others (perhaps older people) use it today is OED sense 3.

> **3. colloquial. Chiefly British. A fuss, a commotion; a tedious or unnecessarily drawn-out process, a rigmarole.**
>
> 1878   Catholic World June 298/2   A thousand hermits have lived
>   before Thoreau, and made no palaver over their social discomforts.
>
> 1892   J. Lumsden Sheep-head 199   Both he and the little boy
>   perished. Much fuss and palaver at the time were made about it in the
>   public prints.
>
> 1920   D. H. Lawrence Women in Love xii. 149   She hated the palaver
>   Hermione made... She wanted anything but this fuss and business.
>
> 1947   H. W. Pryde First Bk. McFlannels v. 50   Inside ma collar's the
>   only place fur the thing [sc. a table napkin]. Ach, it's nothin' but a
>   palaver onywey.
>
> 1967   P. Bailey At the Jerusalem iii. 154   What a palaver there was
>   before the coach left! Chattering away, rushing around.
>
> 1987   D. Adams Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency viii. 53   He
>   went through a palaver similar to his previous one with his coat and
>   hat.

Comment: Which version of OED, WS? Some of us have outlived many updates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is the current online edition, as of this morning. One thing puzzles me, which you may be able to help with. I have always used "palaver", and mostly heard it used as a mass noun. Some of the examples above have it as a count noun. Indeed the phrase "a load of palaver" sticks in my mind.

Comment: I've only ever come across "What a palaver!" / "There was a right palaver" etc. I think the CGEL definition of 'count usage' is easily the most useful; 'palaver' is non-count in both my examples, as you'd never hear "There were two / a few / ...  palavers". Compare "I take a great pride in my achievements".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I only seem to recall usages such as "all that confounded palaver", "a lot of palaver" etc.

Answer (score 4):

In Southern Nigeria, the word 'palaver' is used quite often; although with a very distinct Nigerian pronunciation and in the context of local colloquialisms.

In Nigeria (where many old english words float around as vestiges from the former British Empire), 'palaver' means an argument or a situational problem.  It is often used in phrases such as, "what's all the palaver?"  or "no palaver," meaning "what's all the commotion?" or "no problem" respectively.

Ex. (a) "I heard you two shouting and hurling insults at each other all the way from the corridor.  What's all the palaver?"

Ex. (b) "Have you spoken to Tunde about the spreadsheets?  You haven't?  No palaver, he'll be here soon and you can talk to him then."

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Chicago, since you ask, but have lived all over the US. I've never had occasion to use it myself, but I've seen it a lot in writing, particularly in the work of nineteenth century English explorer Richard Francis Burton.

As someone has mentioned, it is rather pejorative, has racist overtones, and in almost every use I've seen, is used to describe negotiations with, or between, the "natives", whether of Africa, or elsewhere. In short, very much like the usage you came across.

If you look at the OED entry, it's first attested in 1735, and sense 1. is: "A talk, parley, conference, discussion: chiefly applied to conferences, with much talk, between African or other tribespeople, and traders or travelers."

You can see why it's not used as much today, except in the sense of useless talk. It's possible the original meaning has been lost to most people.

Answer (score 2):

In Finnish [*palaveri*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palaveri), not very surprisingly derived from the English *palaver*, is widely used as a somewhat informal synonym for a meeting, and I believe the Danish have derivation of it too.

I personally notice from time to time *palaver* being used to describe a prolonged discussion by some Scandinavian people when they discuss in English,  likely because of the familiar derived word in their mother tongue.

Comment: To clarify: I was referring to English in the context of Scandinavia, for which the mention of the derivation of the words in Finnish and Danish was needed, hence the answer's focus being on how palaver appears in English, not explicitly how it appears in Finnish or Danish. Also, if the question was 'Is "palaver" still in use? (If so, in what part of the world is it used?) In what sense is it used?', I would like to know how am I not answering the question (not meaning to offend anyone, just curious)?

Comment: @V-J In all fairness, technically "it" in the second paragraph refers to "palaveri", not "palaver", so it can easily be misconstrued as if the entire answer is about the Finnish word "palaveri". However, when reading between the lines I think it becomes clear what you mean which is why I too oppose the critical comments.

Comment: @Pickett Yeah now that you mentioned of it, I now saw how the second paragraph could have been misleading, and the description of in what sense palaver is used was too vaguely implied, so I clarified the paragraph to hopefully convey the point better.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I have ever seen that word used in the wild (before this question) is in [Prime Palaver](http://www.baen.com/library/prime_palaver.asp), a series of published correspondence and essays from Eric Flint, in his capacity as "librarian" of the [Baen Free Library](http://www.baenebooks.com/c-1-free-library.aspx).

So yes, *somebody* uses it. Eric Flint uses it. As for biographical info, I believe he grew up in California, but has lived the last few decades in Chicago.

Comment: I believe "Prime Palaver" comes from Isaac Asimov's *Foundation* series (one character actually uses the sobriquet *Preem Palver*).

Comment: @lserni - That wouldn't shock me in the slightest. Eric appears to be a huge fan of "Golden Age" Scifi, and has even gotten some of it republished.

Answer (score 0):

In Danish, 'palaver' [officially means](http://ordnet.dk/ddo/ordbog?query=palaver)

> confused, incoherent and frequently loud discussion, negotiaion or similar.

As a sub-meaning is included a more informal, festive setting - which is the way I've come to know the word used in Danish. (Although it is very infrequently used these days.)

Answer (score 0):

Palaver was used in the old American west as a term for the food eaten on the cattle drives and ranches. My father mentioned his great grandfather using it in the 1930's-1940's in Nebraska.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).